# Responsive absolute positioning with 2 images

Tags: css, responsive-design, css-position, responsive-images

I have an image of a football field with 11 zones(left endzone, right endzone, and zones 0-9.  I also have an image of a football that I'd like to be able to absolutely place in any of these desired 11 zones, and have the ball and field be responsively sized (it will be used on tablet, desktop, and mobile).  I'm also using bootstrap, but for now I've taken that variable out so I can attempt to get it working with my own CSS/HTML.

[image]

I can get it to absolutely position the ball on top of the field and I can get the field to reduce in size appropriately, but the ball stays the same size.  Furthermore, as the screen size shrinks, the position of the ball gets out of whack.  I suspect this is due to the fact that I'm using px units for left/top values.  I've tried getting it to work with percentages (left:10%, top:50%, etc) but it seemed to ignore the left/top when I did so.

I've also tried setting the width and height of the field-container and it respects the percentage, but then it ceases to be responsive.  I'm a back-end dev learning CSS and I'm sure I just missed some crucial but simple aspect of positioning and responsiveness.  I'd rather not resort to some hacky solution where I chop the image into sections which brings its own host of problems.

Is this something better handled with media queries?

**HTML**

```
<div class='field-container'>
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/R4nJuCS.png' class='field' />
  <img src='https://i.imgur.com/OFUsjLJ.png' class='ball' />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.field-container {
  position:relative;
  width:1000px;
  height:200px;
  /* add this to test responsiveness */
  /* width:400px; */
}
.field {
  position:absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.ball {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
}
```

Here is my code-pen:
https://codepen.io/tjans79/pen/ZEWqjQb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
.field-container {
  position:relative;
  width:50%;
}
.field {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.ball {
  left: calc(8.3% * 4);
  display: inline-block;
  position:absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 7%;
  transform: translate(10%, -50%);
}
```

The field doesn't have to be absolutely positioned, but it does have to fill it's containing element.

The ball should have a width that is a percentage of its container in order to make it resize in proportion with that.
You can centre the ball by absolutely positioning it, relative to its container, 50% from the top, and then using `transform` to translate it back up half of its height (50%);
Finally, calc can be used to position the ball on the field. 8.3% is 100/12, that is one of the 12 sections of the field.Adjust the second number to move the ball between sections. The translate function takes 10% just to nudge the ball into place.

Comment: Dude, that's money.  Thanks, worked like a charm.   I spent a lot of time trying to figure this out, glad I was in the ballpark, but I don't think I ever would've found "calc" or the notion of not needing the field absolute.

Comment: Happy to help. Was an interesting problem.